# Sorting a file based on second column in a Tab Spaced file

Tags: bash, shell-script

This may be a duplicate, But I have a Tab separated file and I need to sort the file based on second column which are float values.

`sort -s -k2,2gr -t$'\t'`

The code states it is to sort based on only second column in reverse order for a tab seperated file. But I am getting a wrong answer.

Comment: You might want to use numeric sort: `-n`. Ah never mind

Comment: it did not work.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-sort-5 This is the question. If you could open the link.

Comment: It's better to copy and paste the question text instead of linking to it.

Comment: It is failing the hidden case. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BwcPO9Ad3BT6nAlRKR7DWcwSp1J_rZTgcJUXb0GxYWrnAloZCQIUEaWCP-QZztMCqRB_24quEmrbsoHf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I typed exactly what you have in to the website and it says it worked for me.

Comment: Did it pass the hidden case as well?(you need to submit) the code I have?

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me submit without an account. If you want help you are going to have to actually tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On examination, my suggestion of using `-n` is right:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" $RANDOM $(python3 -c "print($RANDOM / $RANDOM)") $RANDOM; done | sort -n -t'        ' -k2
29712   0.03716599507061539 950
2107    0.08032908116102791 1738
27575   0.37469985135495676 9831
16029   0.6201534733441034  18426
10659   0.7227198549410698  19929
1175    0.8913083459006143  24232
27187   1.1602447494625434  7016
6047    1.6342058354442255  17419
25561   2.026578073089701   4270
21636   14.603404255319148  17159
```

The example data works fine with `-n`:

```
$ sort -n -t$'\t' -k2 test.txt -r | column -t -s$'\t'
Austin, Texas        50.2  68.3  84.2  70.6  33.65  85   0.9   62/58
Baton Rouge, La.     50.1  66.6  81.7  68.1  63.08  110  0.2   52/46
Atlanta, Ga.         42.7  61.6  80.0  62.8  50.20  115  2.1   69/65
Birmingham, Ala.     42.6  61.3  80.2  62.9  53.99  117  1.5   60
Asheville, N.C.      35.8  54.1  73.0  55.2  47.07  126  15.3  39
Albuquerque, N.M.    35.7  55.6  78.5  57.3  9.47   60   11.0  64
Baltimore, Md.       32.3  53.2  76.5  55.4  41.94  115  21.5  53
Atlantic City, N.J.  32.1  50.6  75.3  55.1  40.59  113  16.2  60/54
Boise, Idaho         30.2  50.6  74.7  52.8  12.19  89   20.6  64
Bridgeport, Conn.    29.9  48.9  74.0  54.7  44.15  119  26.2  55/49
Boston, Mass.        29.3  48.3  73.9  54.1  42.53  127  42.8  52/66
Billings, Mont.      24.0  46.1  72.0  48.1  14.77  96   56.9  69
Albany, N.Y.         22.2  46.6  71.1  49.3  38.60  136  64.4  57
Anchorage, Alaska    15.8  36.3  58.4  34.1  16.08  115  70.8  39/60
Bismarck, N.D.       10.2  43.3  70.4  45.2  16.84  96   44.3  64
```

---

By specifying the sort order only on one field, if the sort field has a tie, there might be problems.

Comment: In your answer if you use only -k2 it will sort based on all columns from 2. I did try it replacing the g with n. But it did not work.

Comment: Yes, The example data worked fine. It failed for the hidden case.

Comment: Why did mine fail? where was the difference?

Comment: Thank you, From morning you have helped me in every question I asked.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder see update.

Comment: based on this(http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) I thought we should use -k2,2 isn't it?

Comment: @WannaBeCoder Ah, I misread the manpage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19296/discussion-between-wannabecoder-and-muru).